# Bulk user creation in Azure AD B2B

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

We have a scenario wherein we need to migrate the B2B users from a CSV file. We don't want to send an invite to them again and they reside in a 3rd party IDP.

Is there any way via GRAPH API or PowerShell to create the users in the host tenant? I tried using below body but the source is becoming as 'Azure AD' which is incorrect.

```
{
    "mailNickname": "Test",
    "displayName": "Test User",
    "givenName": "Test",
    "mail": "test.user@customdomain.com",
    "surname": "User",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
        "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    },
    "userPrincipalName": "test.user_customdomain.com#EXT#@abc.onmicrosoft.com",
    "userType": "Guest",
    "accountEnabled": true
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is possible with two MS Graph Requests,

Firstly you need to create the user by below sample post request,

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Adele Vance",
  "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
  "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

Now in second request you need to update the user to B2B,

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}

  {

        "displayName": "Adele Vance",
        "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
        "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"

        "userType": "Guest"

  }
```

**Alternative Approach,**

With the Azure AD B2B [invitation options in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation), you can choose whether or not to send the invitation email, and whether to add the user as a *Guest* or as a *Member*. The [`New-AzureADMSInvitation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/New-AzureADMSInvitation?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlets from the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell module is just a simple wrapper around this API, so the same capabilities are available in PowerShell.

**Invite a user as member without sending email**

With Microsoft Graph:

```js
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "user@example.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://example.com",
  "sendInvitationMessage": false,
  "invitedUserType": "Member"
}
```

With Azure AD PowerShell:

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress "user@example.com" `#`
                        -InviteRedirectUrl "https://example.com" `#`
                        -SendInvitationMessage $false `#`
                        -InvitedUserType "Member"
```

Once the invitation has been created, the user can directly try to sign in to any tenant-specific application they have access to (e.g. https://contoso.sharepoint.com, or https://portal.azure.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or https://yourapp.example.com), using the invited email address as their username.

The first time they do this, Azure AD will automatically detect them as an external user with a pending invitation, and proceed with the required consent prompt to complete the invitation acceptance. Subsequent sign-ins will allow the user to sign in directly. This is described in [Add B2B collaboration guest users without an invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-user-without-invite).

Comment: But the source remains as Azure Active Directory. Can I update that? The source is actually a 3rd party SAML enabled IDP.

Comment: Hi @SushmitaDas, It is not possible to update source. I have updated my answer with an alternative approach which will help.